# Создание хакерских программ на С++

Tags: c++, взлом

На каком уровне и что нужно уметь на С++, чтобы писать реальные программы способные взломать что-нибудь, например, соседский wifi? Если не только нужен С++, то на каких языках лучше всего писать на windows хакерские программы?

Comment: Если, что перебор c помощью словарей это brute force

Comment: можно писать на чистом си, а можно даже на питоне/перле (какой хекер без знания перла?). А почитать лучше чего то по шифрованию для начала (Шнайдера) и по протоколам.

Comment: Нужно знать не столько язык программирования (это всего лишь инструмент), сколько **технологии и как они работают** (т. е. требуется глубокое и низкоуровневое знание аппаратного  стека технологий WiFi, а также используемой в этом случае модели OSI (в частности, адресация, маршрутизация, шифрование)). Вам же надо будет как-то подобрать пароль к подключению, а затем вклиниться в него, разделяя свой трафик и соседский так, чтобы не мешать этому соседу. И тут выясняется такая неприятная деталь, что подобный инструментарий *уже создан* и ничего нового писать, как правило, не надо.

Comment: И если, что я взлом не всегда хорошо. Ты это спецслужбам скажи (хотя я не иду хакером в спецслужбы). В АНБ хакеры работают и этичные (белые) хакеры тоже взламывают.

Comment: Ответ прост - надо знать дофига, а С++ здесь совсем не обязательная составляющая.

Comment: Я не хочу гадить соседу, просто я программист и улучшаю навыки программирования, но иногда хочется создавать безобидные хакерские программы. Например взлом wifi, который не делает сильно плохого, а мне экономит деньги. Существуют хакеры, которые взламывают и на этом зарабатывают, но я хочу стать крутым хакером для других целей

Comment: Ради интереса вот [статейка на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/55700/)

Comment: Я не курю) и не только для этого, например с помощью хакерства можно тролить друзей, пугать их. Хакерство можно использовать на пользу и думаю, что хакерство будет помогать писать безопасный код)

Comment: А, ну если троллить друзей, то тогда имеет смысл.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Скачайте какой-нибудь из существующих наборов хакерских утилит (например, в *[nmap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap)* должно быть что-то по взлому/подбору реквизитов доступа к Wi-Fi) и **изучите их исходный код** (если самоцель — именно *написать*, а не *взломать*).

Согласен, параллельно с изучением исходных кодов потребуется изучать и принципы работы всего, на чём основывается технология Wi-Fi. Но так никто и не обещал, что быть хакером (именно **настоящим хакером**, а не позёром-«кулхацкером») будет просто.

Изучение именно языка программирования — это вопрос второстепенный, поскольку он служит исключительно для написания программы. Однако эту программу необходимо сначала спроектировать, что невозможно без знания предметной области.

Comment: Опять вы минусы привлекаете ответами на плохие вопросы.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, зато на этот ответ можно будет давать ссылку перед удалением будущих подобных вопросов, чтобы эти «хакеры» знали, с чем связываются и не мнили много о себе.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian возможность заработать знак ["реверс"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal).